# Why does fetching from postgresql by Hibernate takes extreme long on AWS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have an environment on AWS with a RDS Postgresql9.6 and a Spring Boot v1.2.7RELEASE application running on a EC2 Instance. Now I want to fetch about 10.000 entries from a table of the Postgresql DB, which takes about 1 minute. If I do this locally It takes about a second to fetch the entities.
I would expect that the fetching would just take some more time than locally like 2 or 3 seconds.
Actually the request takes 1 minute.

To determine if the problem maybe is caused by a bad query I did
`explain analyze  SELECT * FROM view_name where uuid ='4e663553-4271-4d7d-8de9-d7b746787cc6'` which tells me that the execution of the query itself just takes 300ms.
Therefore I thought the performance Issue comes from transmitting the data from the DB to the application. But I don't know how to evaluate this or even how to improve this.

To reproduce this I guess you need a AWS environment with a RDS and an application which just uses Hibernate to fetch from the RDS a table with approximately 10.000 entries.

**EDIT 1**

Persistence and DataSource Configuration.

We are using hibernate and have the the following configuration:

```
hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size=8
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=10
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=8
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.redis.SingletonRedisRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
hibernate.max_fetch_depth=10
hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
```

I should also note that we use ElastiCache Redis with version 2.8.24.

Comment: That query does look very specific (i.e returning a single row instead of 10000). Your local test probably doesn't have 10000 rows, isn't remote (local on your development machine). All that data needs to be transferred over the network which is slow. It also does this in chunks based on the fetch size (default is 10 for postgres) which results in 1000 roundtrips. Which persistency mechanism are you using JPA, JDBC or ...? Please add your datasource (and persistence) configuration to your question.

Comment: Take spring boot out of the equation by running the query from psql (on the same machine where spring-boot runs) and seeing how long that takes.  Something like `time psql -Ac 'select * from pgbench_accounts' >/dev/null`

Comment: The requests did take about 0.3 seconds. So the same like I would do it on a local machine. Therefore I would guess this is more a Hibernate Issue?